# rider breakpoint on F# method

Tags: methods, f#, breakpoints, rider

Is there an example somewhere of a breakpoint on a method in F# under jetBrains Rider?

I start with an "empty" console app, put a breakpoint on `main`, and it has no effect

Comment: A few questions: .NET Framework or .NET Core app? On macOS, Windows, or Linux?

Comment: linux 20.4. . "empty" program for a brand-new project. Works OK on Rider 2019.1.4

Comment: Thanks for the info! What item is preselected in the "Run Configurations" drop-down list next to the run button?

Comment: It is 2019.2.4 where it works OK

Comment: It is 2019.2.4 where it works OK

Comment: Got it, thanks! Then, please file a new issue here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RIDER&c=Subsystem%20Debug%20-%20Breakpoints&c=Technology%20FSharp&c=Assignee%20Eugene.Auduchinok and attach the log files from `Help | Collect Logs`. Thanks!